# Making a screen switch after a few seconds (thread/intent) - Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I am attempting to making a method that on a button click, it will display a layout.
After a few seconds, I want a new activity/layout to be displayed.

Any suggestions on how to do this??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest not to wait on the UI Thread.

You can use a `Handler` for your Task. The `run` method will be executed in the same thread the `Handler` has been created:

```
    //delay in ms
    int DELAY = 1000;

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {            
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);                  
        }
    }, DELAY);
```

Comment: I did something similar, however where i want it to "do something after delay" it does not like when I try call a class

Intent newClass = new Intent(this, ClassName.class); 
        this.startActivity(newClass);

Comment: Do not call this.startActivity(..). Omit the 'this' and just call startActivity(..)

Comment: Elipse is not liking this line of code - Intent class = new Intent(this, Failed.class); - It is wanting me to make it - Intent class = new Intent(); - But then it does not know what class to g oto. Very frustrating.

Comment: Ok. If you write 'this' in the 'run' method java infers 'this' as the Runnable, because you are in a method of the Runnable. You need to be more specific. I edited my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Does the UI need to do anything during this delay? If not, you can just use:

```
Thread.sleep(timeToWaitInMilliseconds);
```

inside your handler for the button. This will stop the UI thread for a few seconds however, your UI will "Freeze" during the delay.

A slightly better option is to use an AsyncTask and a Handler, which is a new thread, and make that thread sleep for the time you want to delay the new activity opening then opening the new activity in the handler.

The asynctask is a bit better for your case I think, as it will allow the user to interact with the UI during your "delay".

More info on AsyncTasks here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: I just tried your suggestion. On the button click, I am asking it to view a layout. The asking it to delay for 5000miliseconds, and then go to the new activity.

For some reason it is delaying for 5 seconds, flashing the layout for a slit second, and then going to the new activity.