# Moving to another activity after a few seconds - Activity is not an enclosing class

Tags: java, android, handler

I am trying to move to another activity after a few seconds in android and I looked up the StackOverflow and found the code in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959666/making-a-screen-switch-after-a-few-seconds-thread-intent-android). The problem is that it gives me an error for the "CurrentActivity.this" It says "CurrentActivity is not an enclosing class"

Here's the code:

```
package mirdak.smartfood;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MyActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

//delay in ms
int DELAY = 1000;

Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {            
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);                  
    }
}, DELAY);
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: use like this ,Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, NextActivity.class);  your intent call from  current activity from another one activity.

Comment: @prakash But I have set the content for CurrentActivity to a different layout called start_up.xml and then I want to move to the main layout which is called activity_my

Comment: @prakash Never mind It just worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass in Intent your actual context, in your case it will be

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
```

Comment: So this is going to show the activity_my.xml layout and then I have to set the content to another layout in the NextActivity, right?

Comment: It seems so, MyActivity and NextActivity is separate activities and you set different layouts in it.